# send sms using way2sms by java program?

Tags: java, sms, way2sms

i would like to know how to send sms to mobile using java program connected to way2sms.i have wrote folloing program but it got error plz let me know what r required
i added way2sms.jar
import com.way2sms.SMS;

```
class TestSMS {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SMS smsClient=new SMS();

    smsClient.send("userid","password","receiving number","message","proxy");

    System.out.println("done");
  }
}
```

I added way2sms.jar and proxy may be null or ""

i got following error:even i used valid user id and password of way2sms site..

```
Mar 12, 2012 10:31:26 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences

WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002

Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.

Logging in ...

Login Failed...

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://wwwd.way2sms.com//auth.cl
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1303)done

   at com.way2sms.SMS.login(SMS.java:132)

  at com.way2sms.SMS.send(SMS.java:75)

  at sms.TestSMS.main(TestSMS.java:10)
```

Comment: `Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002`  i don't know the way2sms - but this sounds like you don't have writing permissions in the folder?

Comment: That looks like a registry key.

Comment: hey i m getting the same problem "FileNotFoundException" plz help me if you got any solution